# What's the easiest way to target a specific block level element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's what i have:

```
<div class="one-third">
<div class="heading clearfix">
<i class="icon icon-folder-open-alt h3"></i><h3> Hello World! </h3>
</div>
```

i need to style the text Hello World! which is inside an h3 element, without styling the "i" element

i don't want to style every h3 i only need that h3.

PS: it's a shortcode generated by a wordpress theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below:

```
i.icon.icon-folder-open-alt.h3 + h3{color:red;}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/DuhTh/1/)

Comment: Thank You. I have been telling that everytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

**UPDATE**

```
.heading, .clearfix, .h3:nth-child(2)
{
    color:red;
}
.icon, .icon-folder-open-alt, .h3
{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i don't want to style every h3 i only need that h3

Comment: thanks but that didn't work it actually styled the paragraph beneath the h3 and every paragraph on the site were styled red :(